# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat cython

Tags: cython, python-3.7

My jupyter notebook gave errors when trying to run cython

The error was: `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

I spent a day reading about it and installed `Windows Visual Studio 2019` as it was suggested to install visual studio. This did not help.

Comment: So.. you resolved your problem? If that is the case then please edit out the answer part in the question and post it as an answer to this question. Don't add the answer in the question itself.

Comment: If you think that this info could be helpful to others add it as an answer to the original question, where the other answers were not satisfactory. Don’t ask the same question again, which won’t be found by anybody.

Comment: Thanks. I was unable to add an answer as I am a new contributor. I thought new programmers like me may get stuck with such small problems so I decided to post it here. I have also answered my own question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation of Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools and selecting C++ in the installer fixed the issue. In Anaconda 3 with python 3.7, cython works fine with visual studio c-compiler.